# Why Program Control is not fetching consumer message from claim?

Tags: go, apache-kafka, sarama

I am trying to implement a Kafka Consumer Group using shopify sarama client. I am kind of confused, how should a  ConsumerGroupHandler be used. Since, I don't know session and claim object. How can I use ConsumeClaim.

Is there some code, I am missing?

```
package kf

import (
    "context"
    "fmt"
    "github.com/Shopify/sarama"
)

type Consumer struct {
    flowEventReader sarama.ConsumerGroup
    topic           string
    brokerUrls      []string
}

func InitConsumer(brokers []string, topic string) *Consumer {
    c := &Consumer{}
    c.topic = topic
    c.brokerUrls = brokers
    var (
        err error
    )
    conf := createSaramaKafkaConf()
    c.flowEventReader, err = sarama.NewConsumerGroup(c.brokerUrls, "flowExecutor", conf)
    if err != nil {
        panic("failed to create consumer group on kafka cluster")
    }
    return c
}

func (c *Consumer) HandleMessages() {
    // Consume from kafka and process
    for {
        err := c.flowEventReader.Consume(context.Background(), []string{c.topic}, exampleConsumerGroupHandler{})
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Errorf("FAILED")
        }
    }

}

type exampleConsumerGroupHandler struct{}

func (exampleConsumerGroupHandler) Setup(_ sarama.ConsumerGroupSession) error   { return nil }
func (exampleConsumerGroupHandler) Cleanup(_ sarama.ConsumerGroupSession) error { return nil }
func (h exampleConsumerGroupHandler) ConsumeClaim(sess sarama.ConsumerGroupSession, claim sarama.ConsumerGroupClaim) error {
    for msg := range claim.Messages() {
        fmt.Printf("Message topic:%q partition:%d offset:%d\n", msg.Topic, msg.Partition, msg.Offset)
        sess.MarkMessage(msg, "")
    }
    return nil
}

func createSaramaKafkaConf() *sarama.Config {
    conf := sarama.NewConfig()
    version := "2.6.2"
    kafkaVer, err := sarama.ParseKafkaVersion(version)
    if err != nil {
        panic("failed to parse kafka version, executor will not run")
    }
    conf.Version = kafkaVer
    conf.Consumer.Offsets.Initial = sarama.OffsetOldest
    conf.Consumer.Group.Rebalance.GroupStrategies = []sarama.BalanceStrategy{sarama.BalanceStrategySticky}

    return conf
}
```

Please help me out.